# Finding a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I've resorted to using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has $16$ elements and if you check there are going to be $10$ of order $4$ and $2$ of order two.

Therefore I've just let $H \leq G$ a subgroup of $S_8$ which has two elements of order $2$ and $10$ or order $4$. For example
$$
H = \{(1),(12),(13),(1234),(1324),(2345),(2435),(3456),(3546),(4567),(4657),(5678),(5768)\}
$$
Is this approach alright, and what might be a more clever way to go about solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find two disjoint cycles of order $4$?

Comment: Sure take (1234) and (5678) but why does that help?

Comment: Study the group generated by those two cycles. What can you say about it?

Comment: How does Cayley's Theorem tell you that such a subgroup exists?

Comment: $16$ isn't a prime, you can't use Cauchy's theorem. $S_8$ is not abelian, you can't use converse of Lagrange's theorem. A group of order 16 can be embedded inside $S_{16}$, you can't use Cayley's theorem. You are searching for a non cyclic group order of order $16$, it is not enough to show the existence of an element of order $16$.

Comment: You're right @DerekHolt will edit.

Comment: @eng2math now that you've solved it let me explain my reasoning. The two cycles are each isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and since they are disjoint they commute. This commutativity allows us to write them as a unique pair $(x,y)$ with $x$ being generated by the first cycle and $y$ being generated by the second. It's this commutativity that allows us to decompose it into the direct product of two groups.

Comment: It has $12$ elements of order $4$ and $3$ of order $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\langle (1234)\rangle, B=\langle(5678)\rangle.$ Then $|A|=|B|=4$ and $A\cong B\cong \Bbb Z_4$.

Since $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$ is abelian, each of its subgroups is normal. In particular, $A'=A\times \{e\}\cong \Bbb Z_4\times \{e\}\unlhd \Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$ and $B'=\{e\}\times B\cong \{e\}\times \Bbb Z_4\unlhd \Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$.

Clearly $A'\cap B'$ is trivial and $A'$ commutes with $B'$.

Consider

$$\begin{align}
A'B'&=\{ab\in S_8\mid a\in A', b\in B'\}\\
&=\{(\color{red}{e},e), (\color{red}{e}, (5678)), (\color{red}{e},(5678)^2),(\color{red}{e},(5678)^3)\\
&(\color{green}{(1234)}, e), (\color{green}{(1234)}, (5678)), (\color{green}{(1234)},(5678)^2),(\color{green}{(1234)},(5678)^3)\\
&(\color{blue}{(1234)^2},e), (\color{blue}{(1234)^2}, (5678)), (\color{blue}{(1234)^2},(5678)^2),(\color{blue}{(1234)^2},(5678)^3)\\
&(\color{pink}{(1234)^3},e), (\color{pink}{(1234)^3}, (5678)), (\color{pink}{(1234)^3},(5678)^2),(\color{pink}{(1234)^3},(5678)^3)\}\\
&=A\times B\\
\end{align}$$

Thus $A\times B$, the interior direct product of $A'$ and $B'$, is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$.

For more details on the difference between an internal direct product and an external one, see Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Comment: I hadn't pieced together that $A$ and $B$ were already isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @eng2math.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Consider $S_8$.

Take, $a=(1234) $ , $b=(5678) $

We know order of a cycle is the length of the cycle.
Hence, $|a|=|b|=4$

Again we know any two disjoint cycles commute.

Now consider,$H=\langle a, b : a^4 =b^4 =id,ab=ba\rangle $

Claim : $H\cong \mathbb{Z_4 ×Z_4}$

Hint: Send generators to generators .

Edit: $H=\{a,a^2,a^3,a^4,b,b^2,b^3,ab,ab^2,ab^3,a^2b,a^2 b^2,a^2b^3,a^3b,a^3b^2,a^3b^3\}$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation for $H$, is it equivalent to $\langle (1234) \rangle \times \langle (5678) \rangle$?

Comment: Ok man. I will explain it. Wait a minute.

Comment: Do you know Klein's 4 group?

Comment: No sorry, for reference I'm at first course super introductory undergraduate level.

Comment: No problem. Keep this as a reference and come back after learning few advanced concept like homorphism, direct product, finitely generated abelian group, sylow's theorem etc. Enjoy your learning.